# Get List Items from list linked by lookup

Tags: 2013, javascript, lookup-column, spservices

I'm making a JavaScript extension for form elements. The goal is to bind it to a lookup and react on change. Since I'm weak at webservices, I'm using SPServices.

```
var lookupFieldInternalName = "LookupOne";

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetList",
    listName: "Spis",
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        console.log(xData.responseText);
        $(xData.responseXML).find("Fields > Field[Name='" + lookupFieldInternalName + "']").each(function() { ... });
    }
});
```

Inside I want to make a query to the list with lookup values. But in the field I get the only thing I have is the lookup's list Guid.

How can I get the lookup list name to query it? Or, how to query a list when all I got is a Guid?

Please provide code examples.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know the lookup list name before hand?

Comment: Well, ofcourse I know what list is the source of lookup data, but that's not my goal :-) I try to make the extension generic for forms, so it bases on information that's provided by SPServices. And the only data I see is the list Guid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GUID or the display name for the [`listName` parameter in SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetList).  Make sure you use the curly brackets in the GUID.

```
var lookupFieldInternalName = "LookupOne";

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetList",
    listName: "{C1AA0A1F-8177-4D64-AC3F-FDCFB31EFCA5}",
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        console.log(xData.responseText);
        $(xData.responseXML).find("Fields > Field[Name='" + lookupFieldInternalName + "']").each(function() { ... });
    }
});
```

Comment: I must've overlooked that when I was reading the documentation. Thank you :-)